# React router nested routes doesn't work

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My task is to open `Main products` on `/` and to open `Misc products` on `/misc` with same layout (header and footer), and to open `About` on `/about` with no layout

```
import React from 'react';
import {render} from 'react-dom';

import {BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Switch, Link, Redirect} from 'react-router-dom'

const About = () => "About";
const Error = () => "404";

class AdvertsList extends React.Component {
    render() {
        let {match} = this.props;

        return (
            <div className="container">
                <header>Header</header>
                <main>
                    <nav>
                        <Link to="/">Main products</Link> #
                        <Link to="/misc">Misc products</Link> #
                        <Link to="/about">About</Link>
                    </nav>
                    <div className="content">
                        <Switch>
                            <Route path="/" exact={true} render={() => "Main products"}/>
                            <Route path="/misc" render={() => "Misc products"}/>
                            <Redirect to="/" />
                        </Switch>
                    </div>
                </main>
                <footer>Footer</footer>
            </div>
        )
    };
}

class App extends React.Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Router>
                <Switch>
                    <Route path="/" exact={true} component={AdvertsList}/>
                    <Route path="/about" component={About}/>
                    <Route path="*" component={Error}/>
                </Switch>
            </Router>
        );
    }
}

render(<App/>, document.querySelector("#app"));
```

And if `Main products` are opened on `/` and `/about` link works fine too, `/misc` link does not, despite all `exact` settings, `404` is returned, i can't access misc products.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your first route only resolves to the root because of the exact property, it won't resolve any other route. So `/misc` automatically skips to your error route.

You can add in the `misc` route as another Route component on the `App` component.
Or via

```
<Route path="/(|misc)" exact={true} component={AdvertsList} />
```

This will resolve both `/` and `/misc` to AdvertsList with the exact property still resolving to true. You can add other routes by adding in extra pipes like `|misc|settings|varia`

Comment: Strange, in my vision `/misc` is not exactly `/`, so `/misc` must be working, but you are right, i'll read documentation more closely.

Comment: The exact property means a route will only trigger if your url is exactly the given path. Since `'/' !== '/misc'` it will skip to another route. Compare it to a regular switch statement where `switch(route) { case '/': ... break; default: break; }`  would activate the `default` handler when your route is `/misc`.

Comment: So, in my original, unfixed variant, `/misc` was not accessible, because it is child of `/` route, and route `/` was not accessible because it was `exact`. So it turns out, if you want to access child route, you must access it's parent first. Right?

Comment: Yes, the component will not load if the route is not triggered. So `AdvertsList`'s render method would never even be called.

Answer (score 2):

I think instead of:

```
<Route path="/" exact={true} component={AdvertsList} />
```

you want:

```
<Route path="/" component={AdvertsList} />
```

Also, for future reference, if you're just setting a prop to `true`, you can just write the prop name.

For example:

```
<Thing disabled={true} />
```

is equivalent to:

```
<Thing disabled />
```

Comment: In that case `Misc products` is working, but `/about` stops

Comment: But if i move `/about` route above `/` in `App` component, everything starts working.

Comment: `<Switch>` will match the first thing it encounters where the `path` matches, so that makes sense.

Comment: Please note that this breaks the `404`-route, since `/` without `exact` will match every route. This will also require you to put to always put the `/` route at the bottom of the switch.

Comment: Yeah, here's an example of a better way to structure things: https://codesandbox.io/s/73plj8pl8q